# How to divide two long doubles in C?

Tags: c, math

I am trying to write a function in C that processes a long into a string that has the long as a storage unit (eg. 1400000 -> 1.40 MB). However, the numbers that it outputs are ridiculous such as 4096 bytes becoming 4233576455 KB instead of 4.09 KB. I have tried many fixes such as casting both the divisor and the dividend, and changing the format in sprintf. Here is the MRE:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>

long double rround(long double in,int places) {
    long double ir = in * pow(10,places);
    return roundl(ir) / pow(10,places);
}

char* parse_size(long indata) {
    char* final = (char*)malloc(30);
    if (indata < 0) {
        indata = -indata;
    }
    indata = (long double)indata;//Force long double over long with no floating point
    if (indata > (long double)2000000000) {
        sprintf(final,"%lld GB",rround(indata/1000000000.0,2));
    } else if (indata > (long double)2000000) {
        sprintf(final,"%lld MB",rround(indata/1000000.0,2));
    } else if (indata > (long double)2000) {
        sprintf(final,"%lld KB",rround(indata/1000.0,2));
    } else {
        sprintf(final,"%lld bytes",rround(indata,2));
    }

    return final;
}
int main() {
    long bytes = 4096;
    printf("Expected: 4.09 KB\n");
    printf("Actual: %s\n",parse_size(bytes));
}
```

If you run this program here, you get this output

```
Expected: 4.09 KB
Actual: 4233576455 KB
```

Comment: `indata = (long double)indata;` can only lose data (when `long` is more bits than `long double` can represent, integer-wise), because you assign it right back to `indata`, which is a `long`. That line is complete garbage. And `%lld` is for printing `long long int`, not `long double`.

Comment: `%lld` is the format specifier for a long long int. Your function is returning a long double...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%lld` is claiming you'll pass a `long long int`; you pass a `long double`, so you're printing garbage (at best it will be trying to print some of the bits representing a `long double` as if they represented a `long long`; on many systems, it will be reading from a wholly unrelated register that hasn't even been initialized to anything specific and you'll get complete garbage). The format code you want is `%Lf`, or `%.2Lf` to limit to two digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Thank you, but it is now printing `Actual: 0.000000 KB`

Comment: @Enderbyte09: Works fine for me. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLdToMwGL3nKb5glhTDAOdisrkt0US9UN/AxHSljCZdS0px/oRnx65lBuYMsVdwen6@Dw4pivGGkKY5Y4LwKqWw2GLOJYnyldfFdL5HPC7FBlJZrTkFpWQlUtSFmAiZ0FBwTGgZwJcH5vQICpaGBedQyB26SMKWem2ZiupKCbC@HDEVQPyLV3seybEyBliV9LVkn9SNwESKNT6EOk7GBOYmEdnXwK2GLpM2j2WAnAwWkByk9sahSxi7J8evvd5dd/Wg5cXxvVSE9paWb1Q5YMd0DkJCxiXWzACFNN/reJZV33mSHE53wrJQRpohu2Loj6LJUwYPt37Y/hbnFV/8iKMknATt4jVQXtLhzMHA578C/502GPV4MupEzoDP@kPT8siq4@F1m2iF@87tW73FTKBeqa2VKcI0mV05eRvo370XlGiazmEaJTMz@4vwgz7lhugK8zmMSnMXdtpsXffz1E3zDQ) Prints 4.10, not 4.09, but 4.10 is more correct anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had put `%lf` instead of `%Lf`

Comment: @Enderbyte09: Yeah, the rules are quite strict, and there's no clear rhyme or reason to them (it's usually historical kruft that forces stuff like this). You just need to check [the tables of conversion specifiers and length modifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 0):

```
char* parse_size(long long indata) {
    char* final = (char*)malloc(30);

    long double indataLD = (long double)abs(indata);
    if (indata > 2000000000) {
        sprintf(final,"%.2Lf GB",(indataLD/1000000000.0));
    } else if (indata > 2000000) {
        sprintf(final,"%.2Lf MB",(indataLD/1000000.0));
    } else if (indata > 2000) {
        sprintf(final,"%.2Lf KB",(indataLD/1000.0));
    } else {
        sprint(final,"%.2Lf Bytes",indataLD);
    }

    return final;
}

int main() {
    long long bytes = 4096;
    printf("Expected: 4.09 KB\n");
    printf("Actual: %s\n",parse_size(bytes));
}
```

This gives

```
c++ version is 201703
g++ 8.1.0
Expected: 4.09 KB
Actual: 4.10 KB
```